# What wrong with my LSTM model? Thanks a lot

Tags: lstm

Guys I have some trouble with LSTM model. I wrote it in pytorch. The model is about to learn and predict the humidity of deeper soil layer. But when it goes to predict, curve the model output will experience significant oscillations, and makes the R^2 lower than the expect. In short, I have no idea with this model so far.

I don't know why and I tried to adjust the hidden size, batch size, learning rate etc, none of them can have a fundamental impact on the results. Online responses often say that this is due to overfitting or underfitting. I have also made some initial adjustments to various indicators, but I found that parameter adjustments did not significantly improve the fluctuation of the curve[The figure shows the test of model learning ability during the training process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANYIM.png)[As shown in the figure, the test after training shows that the prediction set fluctuates greatly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSw1U.png)

Here is my code. I would like to know if I should further optimize the parameters or if there is a problem with my model construction.

```
# read varibles
import h5py
# open HDF5 file
with h5py.File('N:/Python date/lon50lat100.h5', 'r') as f:
    for key in f.keys():
        if f[key].shape == ():
            globals()[key] = f[key][()]
        else:
            globals()[key] = f[key][:]
```

```
import numpy as np
Mean = np.zeros([8,1])
Std = np.zeros([8,1])
def feature_scaling(X):
    Mean = X.mean()
    Std = X.std()
    return (X-Mean)/Std, Mean, Std
# 0-1 normalization
variables=['e', 'tp', 'lai_hv', 'lai_lv', 'swvl1', 'swvl2','swvl3','swvl4']
for i, var in enumerate(variables):
    globals()[var], Mean[i], Std[i] = feature_scaling(globals()[var])
```

```
import numpy as np
# Generate training and testing sets
numTrain = 178500
numTest= 14000

# process entire matrix block
eTrain=e[:numTrain];eTrain=eTrain[:,None].....
XTrain = np.concatenate((eTrain, tpTrain, lai_hvTrain, lai_lvTrain, swvl1Train,swvl2Train), axis=1)
YTrain = swvl3Train

eTest=e[numTrain:numTrain+numTest];eTest=eTest[:,None]....
XTest = np.concatenate((eTest, tpTest, lai_hvTest, lai_lvTest, swvl1Test,swvl2Test), axis=1)
YTest = swvl3Test
```

```
# LSTM model define
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

# Define LSTM model
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Convert the input into a tensor with a shape of (batch_size, seq_len, input_size)
        x = x.view(batch_size, -1, input_size)
        # Initialize the hidden state of LSTM
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        # Pass input into LSTM
        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
        # Extract the output of the last time step of the sequence
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out

# Define parameters
input_size = XTrain.shape[1]
hidden_size = 32
output_size = YTrain.shape[1]
num_layers = 1
# Create model and Loss function
model = LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

# Define optimizer
learning_rate = 0.002
num_epochs = 6000
batch_size = 50
num_batches = XTrain.shape[0] // batch_size
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Define learning rate scheduler
step_size = 600
gamma = 0.8
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size, gamma)

# Train the model
train_data = TensorDataset(torch.tensor(XTrain, dtype=torch.float32), torch.tensor(YTrain, dtype=torch.float32))
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size)
```

```
import numpy as np
# Start training
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()  # Set the model to training mode
    total_loss = 0.0
    for batch in range(num_batches):
        start = batch * batch_size
        end = start + batch_size
        X_batch = torch.tensor(XTrain[start:end], dtype=torch.float32)
        Y_batch = torch.tensor(YTrain[start:end], dtype=torch.float32)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(X_batch)
        loss = criterion(output, Y_batch)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += loss.item()
        
    #Update the learning rate
    scheduler.step()

    # Calculate the average loss over the entire epoch
    avg_loss = total_loss / num_batches
    loss_list.append(avg_loss)

    if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Avg Loss: {avg_loss:.4f}")
```

```
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
# Create test data
test_data = TensorDataset(torch.tensor(XTest, dtype=torch.float32), torch.tensor(YTest, dtype=torch.float32))
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size)

# Test the model
with torch.no_grad():
    model.eval()
    Y_preds = []
    for batch in test_loader:
        X_test = batch[0]
        Y_pred = model(X_test)
        Y_preds.append(Y_pred)
    Y_pred = torch.cat(Y_preds, dim=0)
    test_loss = criterion(Y_pred, torch.tensor(YTest, dtype=torch.float32))
```

Sorry for this is my first question, forgive me for not knowing how to attach my source code files and usage data. But I still hope to receive your generous help！